# Laptop is not always going to sleep when closing the lid using (Arch, systemd)

Tags: laptop, sleep, arch-linux, systemd

Following the Arch wiki, I set up the events of closing the lid so that the machine goes to sleep (including a screen locker). This works about 50% of the time. At other times it will lock the screen but not go to sleep.

I am guessing that *some* process(es) keep it awake but I don't know which ones. Is there a way I can find out which processes keep the machine awake?

I was following [the wiki from Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Power_management_with_systemd). I ended up having the following:

`/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
IdleAction=lock
IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
#UserTasksMax=33%
```

And `/etc/systemd/system/suspend.target.wants/resume@exhuma.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=User resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
User=%I
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
# ExecStartPre= -/usr/bin/pkill -u %u unison ; /usr/local/bin/music.sh stop ; /usr/bin/mysql -e 'slave stop'
# ExecStart=/usr/bin/i3lock -c 000022
ExecStart=/usr/bin/slock
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sleep 1

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Comment: If you're using systemd, please post the contents of your unit file controlling the sleep function, and the link to the wiki guide you used.

Comment: Added the config files and link to Arch Wiki